# Verifying existence of data accross tables

Tags: mysql, exists, calculated-columns

Lets say i have a database with the following two tables:

```
Table_A                    Table_B
id                         val_A
val                        ...
...
```

Now i need to do the following `SELECT` on `Table A`:

```
SELECT id, val, ..., isInB FROM Table_A WHERE ....
```

Where ... is any other fields from `Table_A` that i need and isInB will be either 1 or 0 depending on wheter or not `Table_A.val` exists in `Table_B.val_A`

Can this be done?

Comment: Cant this be done using JOIN?

Comment: @KayNelson don't know - that's why i am asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to `LEFT JOIN` both tables:

```
SELECT ta.id,
       ta.val,
       CASE WHEN tb.val_A IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS isInB
FROM table_A ta
LEFT JOIN table_B tb ON ta.val = tb.val_A
```

- See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae09a/1).

Comment: Works perfectly - was trying another way that worked too but yours is a lot simpler - thanks - cannot accept your answser yet - too soon according to site rules - but you fet this one

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT Table_A.id, Table_A.val, IF(table_B.val_A IS NULL, 0, 1) as isInB
FROM
    Table_A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_B on Table_A.val = Table_B.val_A
```

Comment: your solution also works - and a lot more readable then X L's answer i think - but he answered first - good one though - didn't know about if's in SQL